# How to run a shell command with range value as an argument

Tags: bash, shell, command-line, imagemagick

It would be quite useful for transforming images, for example.

`mogrify -trim -fuzz 40% *.{jpg,png}` is great but it's hard to guess the right amount of fuzz.

It would be useful to do something like this `convert image.jpg -trim -fuzz [10..100+10]% output.jpg` meaning from 10% to 100% with 10% iteration. That would create output.f10.jpg up to output.f100.jpg.

I tried to implement it with custom shell script using some `eval` and replaces but failed to find a convenient and flexible implementation.

Comment: for (( fuzz=10; fuzz <= 100; fuzz += 10 )); do convert image.jpg -fuzz ${fuzz}% -trim output.f${fuzz}.jpg; done

Comment: @Leon `seq` can be used, but the above is more neater

Comment: `seq` should be avoided: it's more expensive and is just as non-standard as the C-style `for` loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `bash`, use a C-style `for` loop, which doesn't require generating the full sequence in advance:

```
for((i=10; i<=100; i+=10)); do
    convert image.jpg -trim -fuzz "outputf${i}.jpg"
done
```

The POSIX-compatible way to do this is with a `while` loop.

```
i=10
while [ "$i" -le 100 ]; do
    convert image.jpg -trim -fuzz "outputf${i}.jpg"
    i=$((i+10))
done
```

Answer (score 2):

The comments speak a world of wisdom. A deterministic iterator with an old fashion for-loop keep things simple.

```
for fuzz in $(seq 10 10 100)
do
     convert image.jpg -fuzz "${fuzz}%" -trim "output.f${fuzz}.jpg"
done
```

Comment: Absolutely @MarkSetchell. Good catch!

Answer (score 2):

Just for fun, you can do it rather succinctly and fast in parallel, with **GNU Parallel** - which is just a Perl script btw:

```
parallel convert {2} -fuzz {1} -trim {2.}-{1}.png ::: $(seq 10 10 100) ::: *.{jpg,png}
```

Or, if you want to do a dry run and see what it would do first:

```
parallel --dry-run convert {2} -fuzz {1} -trim {2.}-{1}.png ::: $(seq 10 10 100) ::: *tga
```

**Sample output**

```
convert a.tga -fuzz 40 -trim a-40.png
convert b.tga -fuzz 40 -trim b-40.png
convert a.tga -fuzz 50 -trim a-50.png
convert b.tga -fuzz 50 -trim b-50.png
convert a.tga -fuzz 60 -trim a-60.png
convert b.tga -fuzz 60 -trim b-60.png
convert a.tga -fuzz 70 -trim a-70.png
convert b.tga -fuzz 70 -trim b-70.png
convert a.tga -fuzz 80 -trim a-80.png
convert b.tga -fuzz 80 -trim b-80.png
convert a.tga -fuzz 90 -trim a-90.png
convert b.tga -fuzz 90 -trim b-90.png
convert a.tga -fuzz 100 -trim a-100.png
convert b.tga -fuzz 30 -trim b-30.png
convert a.tga -fuzz 30 -trim a-30.png
convert b.tga -fuzz 20 -trim b-20.png
convert a.tga -fuzz 20 -trim a-20.png
convert b.tga -fuzz 10 -trim b-10.png
convert a.tga -fuzz 10 -trim a-10.png
convert b.tga -fuzz 100 -trim b-100.png
```